# The speeding train

Tags: lateral-thinking

A healthy man is loitering on a railway track. He sees a speeding train coming towards him. He jumps off the track, but first he runs towards the train.

Why?

Comment: Is this lateral-thinking more than logical deduction maybe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Because he's on a bridge and he is closer to the entrance where the train is coming towards. So running towards the train, then getting off the track is the most optimal choice.

Answer (score 13):

because,

> he was in the entrance of a tunnel, so he has to move towards to the train first.

Answer (score 1):

> So, the new train is coming toward him, and at first the man is running toward it, meaning the man is running in the same direction the train is going(the one he is loitering).
>
> The reason why he does it, which is undependent from any other tricky circumtanses, is that he would fall otherwise, because of his speed will be the same as the trains the moment he touches the ground first. Just imagine, you are running like hell, can you stop asap? Or can you run in different direction? No, you run along slower, and slower, then you will be able to do different actions.

Oh, and sorry for my English, please tell me if it needs clarification, i am from Hungary.